# Debian package creation: binary-arch and binary-indep targets

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I'm trying to create my first deb so I don't know much about it yet. 
This is my 'rules' file at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
export DH_VERBOSE=1

# This has to be exported to make some magic below work.
export DH_OPTIONS

%:
        dh $@
```

At the moment I'm reading documentation and trying to understand how to write more complicated 'rules' files. I'm stuck on 'binary-arch' and 'binary-indep' targets. In short I don't understand what they actually stand for.

The documentation says that package arch is determined by 'Architecture:' line in 'Control' file.

- If the value is 'all' then the package is an architecture dependent.
- If the value is 'any' then the package is an architecture
  independent.

I fully understand this part. But then I start reading man files for debhelper tools.

man dpkg-buildpackage says:

> 5. It  calls  debian/rules  build followed by fakeroot debian/rules binary-target (unless a source-only build has been requested with -S).
>      Note that binary-target is either binary (default case, or if  -b  is 
>      specified) or binary-arch (if -B is specified) or binary-indep (if -A
>      is specified)

man dh says:

> Commands in the binary-indep sequence are passed the "-i" option to
>   ensure they only work on binary independent packages, and commands in
>   the binary-arch sequences are passed the "-a" option to ensure they
>   only work on architecture dependent packages.

then I try to view the default set of commands for 'binary', 'binary-arch' and 'binary-indep' targets by typing

```
$ dh binary --no-act

$ dh binary-arch --no-act

$ dh binary-indep --no-act
```

and get fully equal sets of commands. the only difference is '-i' and '-a' flags after each command.

So the first question is - what is the difference between for example 'dh_auto_build', 'dh_auto_build -a' and 'dh_auto_build -i' ( or some other dh_command ) ?

And another question is - if my 'control' file consists only of packages with 'all' architecture do I need to use binary-indep target, or I can do without it and use only build-arch target in my 'rules' file ?

Answer (score 2):

## The Difference

The target `binary-indep` builds all `Architecture: all` binary packages in your source package. The target `binary-arch` builds all other packages, either `Architecture: any` or packages with an explicit architecture list or some architecture wildcards like `Architecture: linux-any`.

## Why?

The distinction of these two paths inside the build process is relevant if you have a source package which contains both kinds of binary packages, architecture-dependent and -independent: The initial build of the package builds both types of binary packages, but every subsequent build on different architectures only needs to builds the architecture-dependent binary packages as you've already built all architecture-independent packages in the first build.

## Example

Imagine you have a source package called `foo` which builds the binary packages `foo-programs` and `foo-data`. While the programs in `foo-programs` need to be compiled (e.g. because of being written in C) and hence the binary package is of `Architecture: any`, the data files in `foo-data` (images, translations, help texts, documentation, textures, game maps, etc.) are the same for all architectures, hence it's `Architecture: all`. Let's say the upstream version of foo is 1.0 and it's the first Debian package revision of that upstream release.

You first build all the packages on the `amd64` architecture for 64-bit PCs, you'll get `foo-programs_1.0-1_amd64.deb` and `foo-data_1.0-1_all.deb`. But you also want to be able to run it on 32-bit PCs, hence you also need `foo-programs_1.0-1_i386.deb`. But you don't need a second `foo-data_1.0-1_all.deb`, so your build process only requires the `*-arch` targets, e.g. by calling `dpkg-buildpackage -B`.

## Necessity of Explicit Targets

With the minimal `dh` style `debian/rules` it may not needed to explicitly specify targets, since many upstream build systems don't make this distinction, but if they do (e.g. by having a separate `make` target for building the documentation, you can implement that e.g. like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@

override_dh_auto_build-indep:
        $(MAKE) -C docs
```

(Example taken from the `dh(7)` man page.)